# php preg_split with special chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

```
$tags = preg_split('@ @', 'Hello World 1 2  3 45   54', NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($tags);
$tags = preg_split('/ /', 'Hello World 1 2  3 45   54', NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($tags);

$tags = preg_split('@/@', '1/2//3', NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($tags);
$tags = preg_split('/\//', '1/2//3', NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($tags);
```

Why is the last one not working?, what is exactly the difference of @ with / for building php regex?

thx for clarifications

Comment: since there is not reason why `'@/@'` and `'/\//'` should be different, could you please tell us your version of PHP?

Comment: ok (based on your reply to thebod), so the problem is not PHP but the website you are using, see my answer

Comment: know any good online php script tester?

Comment: whatever you can do on this kind of website, you can do better on the command line. Google command line php. If you need HTML output, a shared hosting solution is best for you.

Comment: command line in the sense of `php filename.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tool you are using, [writecodeonline.com/php](http://writecodeonline.com/php), is broken.
If you change the default code to

```
echo 'Hello\ World';
```

it should output `Hello\ World`, not `Hello World`, as it does.

This explains why `'/\//'` breaks: it is seen by this tool as `'///'`, which is not a valid regex. Double backslashes are interpreted correctly, though: `'/\\//'` works (but that's because PHP "sees" `'/\//'`, which is equivalent to `'/\\//'`).

One more check:

```
echo strlen('///'), ' ', strlen('/\//'), ' ', strlen('/\\//');
```

should print `3 4 4`. On [writecodeonline.com/php](http://writecodeonline.com/php) it prints `3 3 4`.

Answer (score 1):

The last one works fine on my machine (PHP 5.3.10, but should work everywhere):

```
thebod@dockmaster:~/Sites$ php
<?php
$tags = preg_split('/\//', '1/2//3', NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($tags);
/////////////////
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Also there is no difference between @ and /, #, ~ and : are also common characters used for sepearting the regexp and the modifiers.
Check out php.net for more information: http://de.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: should work on php 5.0 too, better check those code on your own machine, these online tools always have a lot of restrictions (and maybe problems with the backslash)

Answer (score 0):

Basically There is no difference between @ and  / , because you can use any special characters to preg match. just notice to start and end with same characters you used